# Why I cannot add 'Enter' for Scintilla commands in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, scintilla

I accidentally removed `Enter` from the `Scintilla commands`, and looks like it cannot be added back - the `Add` button is grey that can't be clicked:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no option in Notepad++ but you can edit the **shortcuts.xml** file to restore the original assignment.

The XML file can be found in either of these locations:

- *%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml*
- *%appdata%\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml*
- *Notepad++Portable\Data\Config\shortcuts.xml* when running the portable version

Open the file and empty the `ScintillaKeys` node:

[image]

should become:

[image]

Save the file and restart Notepad++. The shortcut for <kbd>Enter</kbd> should be restored.

Comment: The file might also be at _%appdata%\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml_.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks! I'll add this location to the answer.

Comment: If you installed notepad++ elsewhere, it may also be in the shortcuts.xml within the installation folder. At least that was the case for me (my appdata and program files x86 have no notepad++ files).